# ProxySQL and MySQL cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster, ndbcluster, proxysql

This [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-multi-node-mysql-cluster-on-ubuntu-18-04) describes the set-up of MySQL cluster with one cluster node, two data nodes and one MySQL server. This [article](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/ProxySQL-Configuration) describes the configuration of ProxySQL where, MySQL servers are added into `mysql_servers`.

Are the servers added in `mysql_servers` the MySQL server installed in the cluster? If yes, then there will be only one entry in `mysql_servers` and then, how do we define query rules to point to different host groups?

Comment: (I assume you are talking about NDB Cluster, not some other use of "Cluster"?)

Comment: Yes. As described in the article link.

Comment: You would list all of the servers in mysql_servers and the master node would get identified when proxysql connects. To define the [query rules](https://github.com/sysown/proxysql/wiki/Main-(runtime)#mysql_query_rules).

Comment: @Aaron my question is about the servers that are _to be added_ to `mysql_servers`. The article link posted above has two data nodes, one MySQL server and one master. The question is, do I add just the MySQL server? In which case, how do we define query rules?

Comment: Until I read more, for future searches, this [link](http://lefred.be/content/mysql-group-replication-native-support-in-proxysql/) should be helpful.